# jQuery post - Use Headers (apiKey)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, post

In a asp.net MVC5 project, im trying to do a post that has a header of this sort:

> apiKey: MEV8yv3h2Vk5Wuxq5Bc3YcVMv7fEqCFdKWJer4H3LmL6ntcL

and to do so i have this method.

```
    function MyPOSTCheck() {

    var URLX = "https://bla.blabla.bl/nodeapi/v1/bench/book";
    var Headers = {

        apiKey: "MEV8yv3h2Vk9Wuxq5Bc3YcVMv7fEqCFdKWJer4H3LmL6ntcL"
    }

    var myJSObject = { "userId": 1, "period": "allday", "bench": 1 }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URLX,

        data: myJSObject,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: Headers

    });
}
```

im checking on fiddler what passes, and when i use this method and it looks something like this
[image]

but if i use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) i get this:

[image]

is my method wrong or missing something ?

Comment: have you tried a non-jquery `POST` - I find jquery documentation is often misleading (for instance, where's the `X-Requested-With` header the jquery documentation claims is **always added** )

Comment: Any suggestions on alternatives to jquery post?

Comment: after some reading im guessing this is because of CORS, the api im trying to access is not on the same domain